# Shared views in MVC: View(string, object) gives view not found error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have several action methods that can use the same view. I've tried calling View with eg

return View("~/views/contact/Emails", model);

The view "Emails" exists in the specified directory (Resharper underlines the URL), but when I run the application I get the error "The view '~/views/contact/Emails' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/views/contact/Emails"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're inside `ContactController`, you can simply pass in the name of the view.

```
return View("Emails", model);
```

MVC uses routing to find Views, so it doesn't care about the file path, just the name (at least at this point in the request pipeline).

Comment: That does the trick. Just using the name of the view works. Which suggests that the response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938837/asp-net-mvc-how-to-have-a-controller-in-shared-view is wrong.